# Filesize fails to get the real file size after each append with file_put_contents

Tags: php, file, filesize, file-put-contents

I use file_put_contents to append each file segment to upload big file by segments. I upload the file to OSS after the last segment is appended. But the file that gets uploaded to the OSS is not the whole file. Finally I found out that the library used to upload the file to OSS uses filesize to decide the content size to upload. But filesize does not return the real filesize.

```
<?php
    $cycles = 2;
    $file_path = "test";
    unlink($file_path);
    while($cycles--){
        $bytes = file_put_contents($file_path,"testdata test data hhh",FILE_APPEND);
        echo "Bytes written: $bytes" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "File size after append: " . filesize($file_path) . PHP_EOL;
        echo "File md5 :" . md5_file($file_path) . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Cycle " . (2 - $cycles) . " Done" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo `md5sum $file_path`;
    echo `ls -l $file_path`;
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php
Bytes written: 22
File size after append: 22
File md5 :d23e0e4c8f9e42337038ac8747a9d5a7
Cycle 1 Done
Bytes written: 22
File size after append: 22
File md5 :33786998aa09eb32a2b7d505895bec9b
Cycle 2 Done

33786998aa09eb32a2b7d505895bec9b *test
-rw-r--r-- 1 lf 197121 44  6月 28 10:13 test
```

Comment: `clearstatcache`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
clearstatcache(true,$file_path);
```

Refer to: [filesize manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

> The results of this function are cached. See
> [clearstatcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)
> for more details.